# Azure DevOps Pipeline Capture Output of AWS CLI Task to use in next Task

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm deploying a Lambda layer via the AWS CLI Task type and I'd like to capture the output this AWS CLI command so that I can grab the version # and use it as a variable in the next task.

[image]

I was hoping to use Output Variables but that doesn't seem to do the trick. Is this feasible with my current setup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about this task, but if you use regular CLI commands than you can use variables:

```yaml
steps:
- bash: |
    step_function_state=`aws stepfunctions list-executions --state-machine-arn $(stateMachineArn) --status-filter RUNNING |  jq -r '.executions[]|.status' | head -1`
    echo "State machine RUNNING status: ${step_function_state}"
    echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=sfs;]$step_function_state"
  displayName: "Test Script"
  env:
    AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: $(AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID)
    AWS_DEFAULT_REGION: $(AWS_DEFAULT_REGION)
    AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: $(AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)
```

Comment: Command Line Script task? A pre-req would be install the AWS CLI right?

Comment: Yeah, that's correct https://github.com/aws/aws-toolkit-azure-devops/issues/17